# Android Programming mistake

Tags: java, android

I create an app name of android wallpaper but the problem is that when i clicked on left and right button the next and previous wallpaper does not comes. I tried it lots but failed.

```
public class Wallpapers extends AppCompatActivity {
    WallpaperManager managerr;
    Button B;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    ImageView m;

    int a[]={R.drawable.w1,R.drawable.w2,R.drawable.w3};
    int aa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpapers);
        click();
    }
    public void click()
    {
        m = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        B=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        managerr = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        m.setImageResource(R.drawable.w1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if()
                {
                    m.setImageResource(R.drawable.w2);

                }
                else if(m.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m2).getCurrent())
                {
                    m.setImageResource(R.drawable.w3);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

That's the code.

That's the image of app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have set `onClickListener` only for b1.

change your code follows

```
int currentPosition = 0;

public void click(){
    m = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    B= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    managerr = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    m.setImageResource(R.drawable.m1);

    left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(currentPosition > 0){
                m.setImageResource(previuosDrawable);
                currentPosition--;
            }
        }
    }

    right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(currentPosition < pictures.length){
                m.setImageResource(nextDrawable);
                currentPosition++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have edited my example. Now you only needs a list of drawables, to set previous  or next drawable

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if() has no conditions so it can't works add first `if(m.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m2).getCurrent())`
and then add all the else if you need and finally the else including  `m.setImageResource(R.drawable.w2);`

Second you need is to `setOnClickListener` to both `Button` objects because you only set the listener to `b1` and not to `b2`

For what's `B`?

Why you have an array called `a` with the drawables if you don't access to it fields? You can access to drawables using `a[index]` and increasing or reducing the index number from 0 to 3 or from 3 to 0 when you click `b1` or `b2`. It will be better...